# Eloquent relation collection not returning by property accessor but does if I use relation()->get();

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, database-normalization

I'm having an issue with eloquent whereby when I call `$unit->assets` I am receiving an empty collection. But if I call `$unit->assets()->get()` - I receive a collection with the correct results.

According to the documentation my relations are defined correctly, which also seems apparent given that I get correct results when calling `get()` on the relationship object.

```
class Unit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'organisation_units';

    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MediaElement::class, 'owner_id');
    }
}

class MediaElement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'template_elements';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

Table structure is

**organisation_units**

id | name

**template_elements**

id | owner_id | name | filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Turns out the issue was the fact that I use "assets" as the relation method name. "assets" must be a reserved or already used keyword within models or something. Will update the post when I find out exactly why.</s>

Also had the same issue with the method names "colors" and "templates".

The real issue here, was that I was storing my organisation unit in the session and when retrieving that from the session, the relations were already loaded.

Calling `$model->fresh()` before saving to the session sorted out the issue.

Thanks to those who attempted to help.

Comment: `assets` works for me as a relationship name. Are you using any additional traits in your model? Does the `organisation_units` table have an `assets` column?

Comment: No columns with those names, using traits HasSlug (sluggable) OwenIt\Auditable and SoftDeletes. none of them have any conflicting properties or methods